# BenchMark Frameworks in Java Similar to Criterium

Tags: java, clojure, benchmarking

I am looking for a Java benchmarking library.  I am familiar and happy with the features of the [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) benchmarking library in Clojure.  It has features such as:

```
* Statistical processing of multiple evaluations
* Inclusion of a warm-up period, designed to allow the JIT compiler to optimise its code
* Purging of gc before testing, to isolate timings from GC state prior to testing  
* A final forced GC after testing to estimate impact of cleanup on the timing results
```

And its interface is very friendly

```
(bench expr & opts)
```

Which prints a report of summary statistics such as:

```
 => (bench (Thread/sleep 1000))

               Execution time mean : 1.000803 sec
      Execution time std-deviation : 328.501853 us
     Execution time lower quantile : 1.000068 sec ( 2.5%)
     Execution time upper quantile : 1.001186 sec (97.5%)
```

I am looking for a similar library in Java, perhaps one that exposes a bench method that takes, say a Callable, or a Runnable and prints a similar report.  Such as:

```
  BenchMark.bench(new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() { ... }
  })
```

Does anyone know of a full featured, open source free as in beer library that does this?  Maybe also one that includes memory statistics too?

Comment: When ever you see standard deviation for latencies you know not to take it seriously.  Latencies do not follow a "normal distribution".

Comment: @PeterLawrey Knowing the standard deviation allows non-trivial inferences for (nearly) arbitrary distributions: [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Chebyshev.27s_inequality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criterium lists Brent Broyer's benchmarking article as inspiration: [Elliptic Group, Inc. Java benchmarking article](http://www.ellipticgroup.com/html/benchmarkingArticle.html). It's accompanied by (and in part devoted to providing a description of, although it contains lots of fully general content) a Java benchmarking library of precisely this sort (scroll down a little after following the link above to find the link to the jar and the source download).

The README (included in the complete project download) specifies LGPL3 as the licence.

Comment: You could also just use Criterium to benchmark Java code. If you want to write the benchmarks in Java, you'll just have to provide a wrapper (written in Clojure, probably with AOT compilation, or in Java, calling Criterium functions through `clojure.lang.RT` or the new `clojure.api.API` once an alpha that includes it comes out).

Comment: Thanks Michal, thats it.  After importing the libs this example turns out nicely:  `import bb.util.Benchmark;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;


public class Bench {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Callable<Integer> task = new Callable<Integer>() { public Integer call() { return fibonacci(35); } };
        System.out.println("fibonacci(35): " + new Benchmark(task));
    }
}`  worked great

Answer (score 7):

One of the best benchmarking libraries at the moment in my opinion is [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). It is actively developed by Oracle guys, it is open source, and it is used to micro-benchmark parts of openJDK, including the concurrency API and JavaFX.

The output is very comprehensive and can include time per operation, number of operations per ms, confidence interval etc. You can also choose to introduce threads, contention, sharing for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for Java, jMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/ is the standard when it comes to performance testing (so not quite benchmarking) :).

We use Sigar https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home to monitor the JVMs for all sort of parameters in a "platform independent" manner (so not only what the JMX beans expose).

Answer (score 0):

A similar tool is [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/).

Personally I write my own benchmarks.  It is not simple and has lots of pitfalls but you get a better understanding of what you are really testing.